# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate updating as ObjectId

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema:

```
let PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema( {
    name: String,
    country: String,
    roundResults: [ {
        round: Number,
        result: String,
        points: Number
    } ]
} );
```

When I use `findOneAndUpdate` to update a document:

```
Player.findOneAndUpdate({ id: req.params.id },
    {$push: {"roundResults": result }},
    {safe: true, upsert: true, new : true},
    (err, player) => {
        if( ! err && player ) {
            res.json( player );
        } else {
            res.json( err );
        }
    }
);
```

I get the following **unexpected** result:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "57c9eb55c2a07a401462e3ec",
    "name": "Joe Bloggs",
    "country": "England",
    "__v": 0,
    "roundResults": [
      {
        "_id": "57c9eba11c597d5e1460e4f0"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I don't have a `roundResults` schema but, I get an `_id` as shown above, I would expect to see,:

```
"roundResults": [
    "round": 1,
    "result": "1",
    "points": 3
]
```

Can anyone explain why this is, or how I get this to nest the data I am displaying directly above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you pass literal object for sub documents, it is a `Schema`. And `id` would be generated for that. If it is an array define its type `Array`.

Attention that if you define any schema for a property it is considered as a subdoc and entity so it has `id`

Comment: So should I change my Player `Schema` property roundResult to type: `Array`?

Comment: @MattWebb Yes and is becomes an array. Actually it's up to you if you want structured property data type or not. If you want structured so it would be subdoc.